# Unable to understand this jdbc, ibatis error

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am a noob in JDBC, iBatis. I am trying to have my Java EE app execute a stored proc on a sql server but the server is throwing a weird error which does not make any sense to me. Can somebody help me understand what am I doing wrong.

This is the error:

```
20121221 18:42:38:960 [CONFERENCE] INFO  320 AppController             - Error : Error Occurred while Speakers List data retrival: SqlMapClient operation; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in com/ABCD/conference/model/Conference.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the conference_get_speakers-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (update procedure failed).  
--- Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'imconference..conference_get_speakers'.
20121221 18:42:38:960 [CONFERENCE] INFO  323 AppController             - handleException >>
```

Here is the mapping in the xml file:

```
<resultMap id="result-speakers" class="com.jpmorgan.conference.model.Attendee">
    <result property="confId" column="conf_Id" />       
    <result property="attendeeId" column="attendee_id" />
    <result property="firstName" column="first_name" />
    <result property="lastName" column="last_name" />
</resultMap>
<procedure id="getSpeakers" resultMap="result-speakers">
    {call
    imconference..get_speakers_details(#confId#)}
</procedure>                   
<procedure id="conference_get_speakers" resultMap="result-speakers">
    {call           
    imconference..conference_get_speakers(#confId#)}
</procedure>
```

I am able to execute the stored proc independently on the database. I guess I am making a mistake in mapping the xml file. Any help, ideas would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you guys need more information.

Comment: Are you sure you need double dots in `imconference..conference_get_speakers`?

Answer (score 0):

The general form to indicate the how to invoke your store procedure should have the following form.

```
{call dbname.procname(#param#}
```

For I can see, removing a dot from your sentences should do the magic.